# Linux server monitoring tools

Tags: monitoring

Morning,

I'm looking for a Linux server monitoring tool that will run on Windows machine. Do you know any interesting and worth checking?

If there's no interesting tool, do you know any service allowing me to monitor server - can be paid solution.

Regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Paessler PRTG for some Linux boxes.  They have a free trial.  Install is a snap and discovery is simple.  Support is great as well, even during the trial.  [Paessler](http://www.paessler.com)

Comment: Awesome software! Still having a lot of questions but you can find everything related to this software in Google. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Contact Paessler support directly.  They respond quickly and seem very anxious to assist.  Even during a trial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cloud-based tool [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) to record output of customizable commands at regular intervals. Very handy and useful free tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What kind of monitoring do you need? Will web-interface be enough for you?

If so you can install Zabbix, Nagios, or Monit on your server. You can check how to configure the Monit on your server [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/how-can-monit-help-you-manage-your-linux-server.html) for example.

If you need to have the program on your Windows PC you can try to use [TheDude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude) program. It will allow you to monitor all SNMP data on your server, check it with ping and such a checks. And it's free.